# How do you grant api permission of user_impersonation {scope} to another azure ad app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to grant user_impersonation  = scope rights to Azure AD App programatically .But unfortunately i am not getting the correct GUID of user_impersonation. I took it from another application manifest file but it seems it changes every time. Can someone assist me here.

I tried the below command to grant access

az ad app permission add --id  --api  --api-permissions user_impersonation=Scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the way around by using below approach, Please suggest if it is right

$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId "ObjectId"
$sp.Oauth2Permissions | select Id,AdminConsentDisplayName,Value

For this you get the below :

***Id***                         AdminConsent  DisplayName       Value

fb5a-c16f-4e30-49cd-ad2b3          Access        ddudisplay   user_impersonation

As soon as you have highlighted ID then you can put in the below command

az ad app permission add --id "appid" --api"resourceid" --api-permissions fb5a5asncdb-c16f-4e30-49cd-ada072b3=Scope

and viola it works.